# Svelte use button to fill HTML select elements

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am building a simple attendance marking screen. I want a drop down and a button at the top which a user can select an option and once the button is pressed, all dropdowns will be filled with that option.

[Image of marking screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Uv1.png)

**Fill all selector and button:**

```
        <option disabled selected value="0" />
        <option value="1" class="selector">Present</option>
        <option value="2" class="selector">Online</option>
        <option value="3" class="selector">Absent</option>
        <option value="5" class="selector">Late</option>
        <option value="4" class="selector">Explained</option>
        <option value="6" class="selector">Sick</option>
        <option value="7" class="selector">Class canceled</option>
    </select>
    
    <button class="fillAllBtn" on:click={fillAll}>Fill All</button>
```

Currently the fillAll function does nothing, I am trying to figure out how to get all of the select elements and set their value to the one selected.

**Person file:**

```
    <div class="picwrapper">
        <img src={person.picture.thumbnail} alt="The rock" class="profilePic" />
    </div>
    <div class="namewrapper">
        <p>{person.name.first} {person.name.last}</p>
    </div>

    <!-- displays the attendance history for a given person -->
    <AttendanceHistory {i}/>

    <select class="markSelector" id="selector">
        <option disabled selected value="0" />
        <option value="1" class="selector">Present</option>
        <option value="2" class="selector">Online</option>
        <option value="3" class="selector">Absent</option>
        <option value="5" class="selector">Late</option>
        <option value="4" class="selector">Explained</option>
        <option value="6" class="selector">Sick</option>
        <option value="7" class="selector">Class canceled</option>
    </select>
```

**People List File**

```
 <select class="markSelector" id="fillSelector" bind:value={selectorValue}>
        <option disabled selected value="0" />
        <option value="1" class="selector">Present</option>
        <option value="2" class="selector">Online</option>
        <option value="3" class="selector">Absent</option>
        <option value="5" class="selector">Late</option>
        <option value="4" class="selector">Explained</option>
        <option value="6" class="selector">Sick</option>
        <option value="7" class="selector">Class canceled</option>
    </select>

    <button class="fillAllBtn">Fill All</button>

    <!-- i is used to make sure the correct attendance data is retrieved. i gets incremented for each person -->
    {#each datares as person, i}
        <Person {person} {i} />
    {/each}
    <SubmitButton />
```

The person list file is where I loop through each person and this is also where my current fill button and select are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the select elements are rendered via an `#each` loop all values can be saved to one array with the help of the index and binding the value. Filling this array will then effect all select elements.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/881b3c02bdeb4a6eaaf68cf693731135?version=3.52.0)

```
<script>
    import Select from './Select.svelte'

    const people = ['Tom', 'Sarah', 'Max']

    let selectedOptions = []
    $: console.log('selectedOptions', selectedOptions)

    let fillAllWith

    function fillAll(event) {
        selectedOptions = selectedOptions.fill(fillAllWith)
    }
</script>

<Select bind:value={fillAllWith} />
<button on:click={fillAll}>
    fillAll
</button>

{#each people as p, index}
<div>
    {p}
    <Select bind:value={selectedOptions[index]} />
</div>
{/each}

<style>
    div {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 3rem min-content;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: .5rem;
    }
</style>
```

###### Select.svelte

```
<script>
  export let value
</script>

<select class="markSelector" id="selector" bind:value>
    <option disabled selected value="0" />
    <option value="1" class="selector">Present</option>
    <option value="2" class="selector">Online</option>
    <option value="3" class="selector">Absent</option>
    <option value="5" class="selector">Late</option>
    <option value="4" class="selector">Explained</option>
    <option value="6" class="selector">Sick</option>
    <option value="7" class="selector">Class canceled</option>
</select>

<style>
    select {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! That is what I'm looking for but I have a person component which the select is drawn within. I have updated the question to show.

Comment: @Hayden-McD I don't see a difference in the pattern except that your component is named `Person` instead of `Select`? Just bind the select value inside `Person` to a varible, export this variable and bind it on the component inside `People List File` to an index of an array. On button click fill the array with `selectorValue `